# extracting a new dataframe consisting of top values for all values in a column

Tags: r

For example, I'm currently trying to figure out the maximum possible height of a pitcher and catcher duo, so I'm going to use a unique Id for each individual team season and extract the largest value for "height" among both pitchers and catchers.

here's what I have so far:

```
library(Lahman)
Battery <- Appearances %>% filter(G_p + G_c > 0)
Battery2 <- left_join(x = Battery,y = People, by = "playerID") %>% mutate(teamyear = paste0(yearID,teamID)) %>%  select(teamyear,playerID,G_all,G_c,G_p,height) 
Battery2 <- Battery2 %>% group_by(teamyear)
Pitcher <- Battery2 %>% filter(G_p > 0)
Catcher <- Battery2 %>% filter(G_c > 0)
```

so each row of Pitcher and Catcher is something like

DET2001 | anderma01 | 62 | 0 | 62 | 76

and I need to create a new table that only takes the highest value for height among each teamyear ID (e.g. "DET2001" )

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

While you do not have a reproducible example and it does not become obvious, what variables you actually need, I can offer a general solution to get the best of each group to a new data.frame:

```
df = data.frame("teamyear"=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                "Score"=c(5,3,2,34,5,6,7,4,3,4,7,2),
                "Othervar"=rnorm(12,0,1))

best = df %>% group_by(teamyear) %>% filter(Score==max(Score))
```

The result would be the highest mark for each value of `teamyear`:

```
> best
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   teamyear [3]
  teamyear Score Othervar
     <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
1        1    34   -2.25 
2        2     7   -1.92 
3        3     7    0.201
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. %>% filter (height = max(height)). 

I'd do it separately for Pitcher and Catcher and then merge the two by teamyear & have a "combinedheight" new column. I probably should have just cut that aspect for the question as it doesn't provide any relevant information to this question.